# How to compile PHP / PECL APD for MAMP / Snow Leopard?

Tags: php, mamp, pecl, i386

When I'm trying to use pecl to install apd it compiles the extension for a 64 bit system. Since MAMP needs extensions in i386 mode, apache won't load this apd.so file.

So how can I force pecl to compile the extension in i386 mode?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Let you try the blow commands.

```
% pecl download apd-or-whatever
% tar zxvf ***
% cd the-directory
% /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/phpize
% ./configure CFLAGS="-arch i386" --with-php-config="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/php-config"
% make
% make install
```

I'm using MAMP1.8.4 with manually compiled PHP5.3.2. In MAMP1.9.x, the paths of phpize and php-config are different.